# ACCESS VBA selecting multiple values from listbox and executing the query name

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, recordset

My intention is to have user select one or several query names from the listbox and prompt the execution of queries with those names.

So far, I have this code:

```
Private Sub Command43_Click()
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim valSelect As Variant
  Dim strValue As String

    For Each valSelect In Me.Combo29.ItemsSelected
    strValue = strValue & "'" & Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect) & "',"
    strValue = Left(strValue, Len(strValue) - 1)

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strValue)

    Debug.Print rs
   rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Next valSelect
MsgBox "Complete!"
End Sub
```

When running the code, I get error that Access can't find the query name.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only open one query with one command, so try:

```
For Each valSelect In Me!Combo29.ItemsSelected
    strValue = Me!Combo29.ItemData(valSelect)
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strValue)
    Debug.Print strValue, rs.RecordCount
Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

And do rename your controls to something meaningful.

Comment: I am getting an error at Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strValue) stating it's an Invalid Operation.

Comment: The code above is only the snippet with the loop. You'll still have to Dim rs.

Comment: rs is dimmed, but same error comes out:    Private Sub     Command43_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim valSelect As Variant
Dim strValue As String
    For Each valSelect In Me.Combo29.ItemsSelected
        strValue = Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect)
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strValue)
        Debug.Print strValue, rs.RecordCount
        Next
        rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
MsgBox "Complete!"
End Sub

Comment: And valSelect is a number and strValue is a string?

Comment: valSelect is Variant and strValue is a string. However here's an update to my code that I managed it do what I needed (Run selected query names from a listbox (whether single or multiple selection) -- Private Sub Command43_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim valSelect As Variant
Dim strValue As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
    For Each valSelect In Me.Combo29.ItemsSelected
        DoCmd.SetWarnings (Warningsoff)
        strValue = Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect)
        DoCmd.OpenQuery (strValue)
        Next
        DoCmd.SetWarnings (Warningson)    
MsgBox "Complete!"
End Sub

Comment: by looking at the above code, can you let me know what issue I should consider or problem that I may run into with this code. I read elsewhere that Warningson or off is not really a good practice. Thank you!

Comment: You could use `CurrentDb.Execute strValue `  ... it won't pop a warning.

Comment: Thanks for helping with the looping. It helped me solve the issue.